# Parsing xml data before string using jsoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, xml-parsing, jsoup

I need to get recipe  ingredients separatly from tags:

```
    for (int i=23233 ; i<100000; i= i+1000){
         url = "site adress"+ i+"/";
         try {
              document=Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(0).get();       
              writeteste(i);
              Thread.sleep(3000);       
         } catch (IOException e1) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

I am using this method to parse one site:

```
private static void writeteste(int recnum) 
{
     Elements destinys = document.getElementsByClass("recipe-tags-tastes");
     Iterator<Element> ite = destinys.select("a").iterator();       
     int ix=1;   
     while(ite.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(recnum +" ; " + ix+" ; " + ite.next().text() );
     ix++;
}
```

this is the code that i am parsing:

```
<br>
<div class="recipe-tags-tastes"> <div class="gray">     
<strong>Tastes:</strong>    
<a href="site adress">sweet</a> 
&nbsp;  </div> <div class="gray">   
<strong>Tags:</strong>      
<a href="site adress">обед</a>  
&nbsp;      <a href="site adress">ужин</a>  
&nbsp;  </div> </div>
<div class="clear">
</div> 
<br>
```

the output that i have is tastes and tags together, and i need to get tastes, and after that tags:

what i have:
23233 ; 1 ; sweet
23233 ; 2 ; dinner
23233 ; 3 ; supper

here is what i need:

taste:

23233 ; 1 ; sweet

tags:

23233 ; 1 ;supper

23233 ; 2 ;dinner

what should i write inside jsoup query to get data from this code separately before word "Tags" and after it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be selecting that based on div with "gray" class like

```
for(Element grayTag :  doc.select(".gray")) {
    System.out.println(grayTag.select("strong").text());
    int ix = 1;
    for(Element hrefs : grayTag.select("a")){
        System.out.println(recnum + "; " + ix + "; " + hrefs.text());
        ix++;
    }
}
```

If recnum is 23233, for the given html this will print

```
Tastes:
23233; 1; sweet
Tags:
23233; 1; Dinner
23233; 2; Supper
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks for your help, now it works:

```
System.out.println("taste : ");
Elements destinys = document.getElementsByClass("recipe-tags  tastes");
Element grayTag =  destinys.select(".gray").first();
// System.out.println(grayTag.select("strong").text());

 int ix = 1;
 for(Element hrefs : grayTag.select("a")){
        System.out.println(recnum + "; " + ix + "; " + hrefs.text());
        ix++;
 }

 System.out.println("tags : ");

 Element secondgrayTag =  destinys.select(".gray").last();

 int ix2 = 1;
 for(Element hrefs : secondgrayTag.select("a")){
 System.out.println(recnum + "; " + ix2 + "; " + hrefs.text());
 ix2++;}
```